# this2. is not a function

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm getting the error "this2. is not a function"[image]

I tried a few solution i found on google but still cant fun a way to call the function.

My main purpose is to call a action function in a action file. Had some issues so i plan to call a function first then try call that action.

```
 viewJob(){
    console.log("View");
}

renderItem({ item }) {
    return(
        <Card>
            <View style={{height:300}}>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.detailWrapper}>
                <Button
                    title="Apply"
                    onPress={() => this.viewJob()}
                />
            </View>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

**Update**

```
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{ marginTop:10 }}>
        <FlatList
            contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
            data={this.props.jobs}
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)} // I didnt bind this , which led to the error above
        />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is this the exact code are you working on? This code block should work. Doesn't seem like have any problems.

Comment: @bennygenel let me try delete my node_module file and try again. Give me 5mins

Comment: Where are you calling the `renderItem` from?

Comment: @bennygenel https://gist.github.com/rainbowhat/ff2176a8b98311019b8789d5a7fe77a4

Comment: Can you provide an example reproducing this problem? https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: Change `renderItem={this.renderItem}` to `renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}`

Comment: Use arrow functions, or bind your functions.

Comment: @Dan you mean use arrow functions on render() ''s renderItem??

Comment: Every time you write and use a function that does not belong to `Component` in React, you must either `bind` or use arrow functions. What functions belong to `Component`? Life cycle functions (`componentWillMount` etc), `setState`, `forceUpdate` and `render`. Without using arrows/binding, `this` equals `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the method

```
render(){
  return(
      <View style={{ marginTop:10 }}>
      <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          data={this.props.jobs}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)} 
      />
      </View>
  );
}
```

**Note**: if you use arrow function then you do not have to worry about binding

You can read more about when to bind from [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)